# Subtract & divide frequency counts created by count_values after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am just getting started with pandas/ python so unfortunately I still have to ask silly questions.
I have a df with a column with subject id and then a column coded 1 or 0 like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1] * 4 + [2] * 4, 
               'accuracy' : [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
df

    ID  accuracy
0   1         1
1   1         1
2   1         0
3   1         1
4   2         1
5   2         1
6   2         0
7   2         1
```

I would need to groupby ID first, get the frequency counts of zeros and ones and then subtract & divide these frequency counts like this:
(frequency count ones - frequency count zeros/ number of total counts). So for ID 1 this equation would read ((3-1)/4). Using this,

```
 df.groupby(['ID'])['accuracy'].value_counts()
```

I get the frequency counts for the zeros & ones per ID, needed for my subsequent calculation. But I'm unsure how to go from here, or whether an entirely different approach like agg and a lambda function or some approach using apply (both of which I just started to learn) would be a better approach. The output would ideally look something like this:

```
id    accuracyTotal
1     0.5
2     0.5
```

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df.groupby('ID')['accuracy'].apply(lambda p : 2.*p.sum()/p.count() -1)
```

Assuming that:

O : count of ones
Z : count of zeros
N : total count = O+Z

I used the fact:

Z = N - O

Hence :

(O - Z)/N = (2*O - N)/N = 2*O/N -1

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately, using your suggestion I get 0 as output for both IDs (when I use the example df from above), which is different from the output I was aiming for (0.5 for each ID in this case).  Is it possible that the equation is a little different? (O-Z)/N= (O-(N-O)/N; is it really possible to rewrite to (2*O-N)/N? I'm sorry for my shaky math but the results just seem different.

Comment: @VanessaS. This is strange. I tested it and it gave the correct output. Are you sure you copied it correctly? please check again...

Comment: I copied both my code for the example df & your suggested code and I get this as an output:                                                                                               
df.groupby('ID')['accuracy'].apply(lambda p : 2*p.sum()/p.count() -1)
Out[4]: 
ID
1    0
2    0
Name: accuracy, dtype: int64

Comment: @VanessaS. Oh, are you using python 2?

Comment: Yes, Python 2.7 & Pandas, I am sorry, didn't know that this was relevant here, else I would have mentioned it before. I'm sorry.

Comment: @VanessaS. It's ok. The division in python 2 is different from python 3. in python 2 the expression `1/2` will give `0` (integer division), while in python 3 it will give `0.5` (float division). Hence the wrong output. I will update the answer :)

Comment: @VanessaS. Just added a dot `.` after the number `2` in the expression. That should do the trick.

Comment: this is a smart formula!